# How would you go about achieving this type of folding animation?

Tags: animation, animation-nodes

https://www.instagram.com/p/BqFwidflF6j/?utm_source=ig_share_sheet&igshid=96chkl8ig9f0

I’m guessing it would be possible with animation nodes but wouldn’t know where to start.